# Access publicly accessible service on host from Dokku guest

Tags: networking, dokku

We are converting to Dokku, and as a part of this process the database (PostgreSQL) will remain running directly on the host for the time being.

The database is used by serveral servers spread around the Internet and accessible using its public IP.

I can `psql` to it from any server, including the server where it's hosted.

However, from inside the Dokku guest running on the same server I get `timeout`. It would appear somewhere access to it is being blocked.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: With which URL do you try to access the database (127.0.0.1, localhost, IP, domain name,...)? You write "public IP", is that true?

Comment: I tried 127.0.0.1, localhost, using the domain name as well as the public IP. Yes, it is true. I never got around to solve this issue, instead we found a work-around in which we could migrate to using a Dokku postgres instance.